# Why is Windows finding malware in a sparsebundle?

Tags: windows, windows-10, time-machine, windows-defender, sparsebundle

I'm copying over a sparsebundle containing some Time Machine backups from my mac onto my Windows machine's drive. While copying, Windows Defender starts complaining about a threat called `Exploit:Win32/ShellCode.gen!C`.

When I look at the details of the threat, it says it comes from one of the sparsebundle bands (i.e. `D:\time_machine.sparsebundle\bands\1051d`). Any ideas what could be going on here? Am I putting my system at any risk by leaving this file in? I imagine removing it would break the whole sparsebundle.

Comment: Because it's matching the signature of the malware.  Sounds like a false positive it's from your own backups

Comment: Yes, looks like a false-positive. Some of my older network tools are detected like that too.